# WiFi и мышь (радиоканал)

Tags: wifi, мышь

Приобрел мышь  Defender Optimum MS-125 Nano для ноутбука. От "синего зуба" отказался с целью экономии ресурсов питания мыши. Сразу резко упала скорость WiFi. Это характерно для данной модели или для любых с радиоканалом?

Comment: выкиньте мышь. кроме компании начинающейся на букву L и заканчивающейся на букву h никто не умеет делать офисные беспроводные клавы и мыши. А Defender вообще ничего делать не умеет, даже салфетки у них отстойные.

Comment: салфетки нормальные - Вы, @eicto , видимо не те юзаете... :)

Answer (score 1):

Частота канала мыши, видимо, перекрывает Wi-Fi по частотам...
[почитайте инфу от Zyxel](http://zyxel.ru/kb/2082)

Comment: В этом я не сомневаюсь (2.4 Ггц). Но диапазон достаточно велик... Возможно есть мыши, сканирующие диапазон, и выбирающие свободный участок?

Comment: Проще поменять канал у Ву-Фы: в статье описано с помощью какого ПО. Не думаю, что мыша имеет свободу выбора :)  Итак, посредством этого ПО сканим каналы (обязательно с включенной крысой) - ПО нам покажет наиболее свободный. В настройках рутера устанавливаем предложенный канал и работаем на нем. Возможно придется настроить и в драйвере адаптера в ноуте.  Вообще, за исключением некоторых случаев, считаю беспроводные клавы и мыши излишним баловством. Вы, как раз и напоролись на случай, который иллюстрирует мое мнение.

Comment: Justicet, спасибо за помощь. Здесь мы видим проблему с разных сторон. Я, как пользователь, Вы, как администратор. WIFI’ем регулярно пользуюсь в 3-х местах. И только в одном я могу переключить канал роутера. “Баловсто” для меня связоно с кучей ”концов” для различных уст –в и приборов.  Но, все равно, спасибо.

Comment: Ну чтож - тогда остается мышка с хвостиком :)  >Justicet, спасибо за помощь.  Не за что.